# Lodash transform not transforming object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm doing something wrong and can't see it. My goal is to update the data value in my returned ajax call collection. I'm using [_.transform](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#transform) I can see the data update in the console, but the object is not transformed as the output of the lodash method. I'm sure I'm overthinking/missing something. Any insight would be great

```
.then(response => {
    if(response.data){
      var arr = response.data;
      arr.forEach(data =>
        _.transform(data, (item, val, key) => {
          if(/(date)/i.test(key)){
            val = moment(val, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z').format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a");
            item[key] = val;
            console.log('data test ', item[key]);
          }
        }, {}))
      self.setState({tableData: response.data._embedded.organizations})
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if I am wrong but I think lodash's transform returns new objects/arrays, it doesn't modify the ones you iterate through. Doesn't matter how much you change the data variable inside the transform, it won't change unless you re-assign it when the transform has finished.

Comment: It also only transforms the object shallowly.  OP wants a deep transform.

Comment: so if I set a new assignment to the transform, it should be the newly returned object/array. I'll try that